# What is the meaning of 取っ替える

Tags: words

From the lyrics to 'indigo love story' by indigo la End:

> 僕らは命を取っ替えた

Can't find this in the dictionaries I have access to (takoboto android app and jisho.org - also let me know any dictionary reccomendations if you like)

Comment: Any reason to think it's not just, kind of a flourish on 取替える?

Comment: Do people here really have a good reason for not even thinking about using a monolingual dictionary at times?  https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8F%96%E3%81%A3%E6%9B%BF%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-342229#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

Comment: In the reply to leebo: because of the different spelling. I dont have the experience or confidence of to assume so so I thought I'd ask because I thought the purpose of this site was to ask questions when you've been unable to confidently look up the answer yourself

Comment: In reply to electur: less think about, more think of.. it didn't strike me at that moment but a monolingual dictionary does seem to the way to go since you mention it

Comment: But is there also any reason why people feel the need to talk down to others and be rude to others on here? I appreciate the need to regulate usage and minimise people asking lazy questions, or for direct translations etc, but it often seems like quite an unfriendly, disparaging environment. Think I've had enough of it anyway...

Comment: Pootan, no one is being rude, l'électeur is just being direct. When you don't find something in your usual dictionary, always try a simple Google search like: ' "取っ替える" とは' (with the phrase you're searching for in quotation), and then in most cases you will get simple explanations in Japanese, like references to kotobank that l'électeur gave you. It is also a very good way of finding difference in nuance between homonyms and kanjis, e.g. "換 代 替 変 違い". Starting a new thread here, or in any other Forum for that matter, should always be a last resort.

Comment: @Pootan `let me know any dictionary recommendations if you like` --> How about this one: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/取っ替える

Answer (score 3, accepted):

とっかえる is a colloquial contracted way of saying とりかえる (取り替える).

This contraction (促音化) occurs in several compound verbs (複合動詞), eg:

> [吹]{ふ}き[飛]{と}ぶ →　ふっとぶ
>   [追]{お}いかける → おっかける
>   [突]{つ}き[返]{かえ}す → つっかえす
>   たたき[切]{き}る →　たたっきる
>   [差]{さ}し[引]{ひ}く →　さっぴく
>   ぶち[壊]{こわ}す →　ぶっこわす

etc...