# Is 引っ張る a compound verb?

Tags: compound-verbs

AFAIK compound verbs (複合動詞) are formed by prefixing 連用形 (ren'youkei, or stem form) of one verb to another "full" verb, e.g.:

- 巡り合う＝巡る(めぐり）＋　合う
- 生み出す＝生む（生み）＋ 出す

And so on...

However, `引っ張る` seems to not fit this pattern and feels like it was formed by combining `引く`+`張る`, and not `引き`+`張る` which would result in  `引き張る`.

Apparently there *are* compound verbs with `引き`, e.g.:

- 引き出す
- 引き受ける
- 引き返す
- 引き止める

Even more interestingly, there is a verb that exists in both variations: `引き越す` and `引っ越す`, although I don't think I've ever seen the former outside of the dictionary.

So, is `引っ張る` a compound verb? If not, is there a term for such verbs and are there others?

Comment: Reminded me of this..  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54343/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, 引【ひ】っ越【こ】す pairs with the older 引【ひ】き越【こ】す form, which doesn't see much use in the modern language.  Along the same lines, modern 引【ひ】っ張【ぱ】る is a shift in pronunciation of older 引【ひ】き張【は】る, which more clearly shows the regular compound-verb structure.

This kind of sound shift is a regular feature of the language.  See also the answer linked at [Why is ふとんがふとんだ a pun?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56620/why-is-%E3%81%B5%E3%81%A8%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C%E3%81%B5%E3%81%A8%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0-a-pun/56621#answer-56621), which shows and links to other similar examples of regular compound verbs (`[VERB in the 連用形]` + `[VERB]`) that have shifted to this kind of 促音【そくおん】 (geminate or doubled-consonant) phonology as a kind of contraction.